What is this unknown FPS counter?
This FPS counter appeared from nowhere. It's visible on top-left corner of active window.
Here, green "33" from BlueStacks player - Android emulator:



Static content apps don't show it, Word and Textpad:




Paint.Net, image editor, shows it twice:



VLC Player shows it:



But Chrome/YouTube does not show it:



I have no idea where it came from. I do know it's not from Nvidia Control Panel or GeForce Experience and not a setting of any of these programs.
This is driving me nuts, I wonder if anyone has ever seen it and knows how to get rid of it!?
Any help highly appreciated.

Have you installed any software related to gaming or recording video that might show FPS? It could be from Nvidia Shadowplay. Does Alt+R or Alt+F12 disable it?

It's gone now. I did not find source for it. Previous reboots did not remove it. I don't know if Shadowplay is installed, if it comes default with nvidia driver then it is. Othwerwise not, I don't have GeForce Experience installed.


Open an application that causes this value to display.
Download and run Process Explorer (by Microsoft Sysinternals).
In the toolbar in Process Explorer click the target-shaped icon titled "Find Window's Process" and drag this over the FPS number showing on your display.
Observe what Process Explorer tells you about the application generating this value.

